# How to add elements to the top of UITableView without using the insert method?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a tableView like Twitter timeline controller, so I get new messages and I want to show new messages on top of tableView, currently, I insert new messages to the first index of my array and then reload tableView, but that's very expensive.
I get about a hundred messages every second. How can I handle this without inserting it into the first index of the array?

Note: All the messages must be sorted by date.

Comment: If you insert to the top, don't use reloadData(). Use [`insertRows(at:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614879-insertrows) instead.

Comment: it's expensive because I inserting to the first index of the array not reloading tableView

Comment: That's not expensive at all! You're only adding one cell!

Comment: Inserting to the first index is overhead

Comment: How is it overhead?

Comment: When we insert to an array it has O(n) time complexity and it depends on the length of the array

Comment: Would it help to append messages and use the index path row to offset from the end of the array instead of the start?

Comment: @sadeghbitarafan I did not know that

Comment: @PhillipMills That seems a good solution but how can I do that?

Comment: Maybe you can try adding new messages in a [batch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/2887515-performbatchupdates), instead of one by one?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple version of what I suggested in the comments.  Assume a UI with a basic table and a button.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet var numberTable: UITableView!
    var content = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return content.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "content_cell", for: indexPath)
        let offset = (content.count - 1) - indexPath.row
        cell.textLabel?.text = content[offset]
        return cell
    }
    
    @IBAction func addAnother(_ sender: UIButton) {
        content.append("\(content.count + 1)")
        numberTable.reloadData()
    }

}
```